# How to fit image height to the parent div's height

Tags: html, css

I want that the image height fits to the parent div's height, but the image is overflowing. How can I resolve this?

```css
.image-parent{
    max-height: 50%;
}
img{
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-parent">
     <img src="example.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: You may find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90178/make-a-div-fill-the-height-of-the-remaining-screen-space) helpful too.

Comment: For seeing the issue at first glance i added an image that works in this stack snippet, made the background of the parent grey and wrapped all in a container with a defined height in ```px``` so that the img-parents height in ```%``` has an effect.

Comment: So here is the example what I want. https://worldwide.kia.com/eu/at/de/ev6/reserve look the"vehicle__image" class. That is the parent div.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to set a height (without max) and the image fits automatically.

**Working example** (i added your old example for comarison):

```css
.container{ 
    height: 400px;
}
.image-parent{
    height: 50%;
    background-color: grey;
}
.old-image-parent{
    max-height: 50%;
    background-color: #bbb;
}
img{
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
     <div class="image-parent">
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/300" alt="">
     </div>
     <div class="old-image-parent">
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/300" alt="">
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What if the parent's height is instead defined by a flex box that's intended to fill the remainder of the page height?

Answer (score 1):

Mention the height for body and set max-height of the image to 100%

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.image-parent {
  height: 50%;
  background-color: grey;
}

img {
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-parent">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b6/Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png" alt="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is necessary to set `overflow: hidden` for container to prevent oveflowing:

```
.image-parent {
  max-height: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100px;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: contain
}
```

An example:

```css
.image-parent {
    max-height: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100px;
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: contain
}
```

```html
<div class="image-parent">
     <img src="http://blog.w3c.br/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/css31-213x300.png" alt="an image">
</div>
```

Comment: This just hide the overflowing image, I want that the image fits to parents height.

Comment: @venndi please, see my updated answer

Comment: with that solution the width fits to the parent element, but not the height. So the image is cut off.

Comment: So here is the example what I want. https://worldwide.kia.com/eu/at/de/ev6/reserve/ look the"vehicle__image" class. That is the parent div.

Comment: @venndi please, see my updated answer

Comment: ```overflow: hidden``` is not necessary here. Just open the browser console and deactivate it - there is no difference. Also ```object-fit: contain``` only centers the image (when used with ```width```) but has no effect for the overflow since the fixed ```height: 100px``` managed it...

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
.image-parent{
    max-height: 50%;
}
.image-parent img{
        object-fit:contain;
        height:100%;
}
```

Comment: I tried it out, but nothings happened.

Comment: It's work fine for me .

Comment: Not really. Have you tried with a bigger image? It's just really nothings happened.